# Calculate percentage increase using math formula

Tags: javascript, math, ecmascript-6

I have a function that calculates percentage increase of 2 numbers:

```
const 1st_num = 50
const 2nd_num = 100

percentage = ((1st_num - 2nd_num) / 1st_num) * 100  // -100
```

It seems correct but what if the 1st number is 1?

```
((1 - 50) / 1) * 100 // -4900
```

I don't see it making sense anymore. What am I missing?

Comment: @Durga are you sure? so from 1 to 50 it decreased -4900% ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are computing a delta variation in percentage between 2 numbers, it should be the other way around:

```
variation = ((num2 - num1) / num1) * 100
```

Last but not least, your delta can be over 100%

For example, imagine at

- t1=10 and t2=11 -> your delta will be computed like this : (11 - 10)/10, so  you have an increase of 10%
- but if you have t1=10 and t2=100 -> your delta will become (100 - 10)/10, so you have an increase of 900%

Comment: so what should I do? you don't have an answer.

Comment: check which one is bigger then place the bigger number to deducte the smaller one?

Answer (score 2):

First up all your question is more suitable to somewhere in math forums:

Your formula is right just change it as follows to get increase change in positive numbers:

`percentage = ((2nd_num - 1st_num) / 1st_num) * 100  //` 100%

However your treatment with 1 is exactly right.

4900 %  **In other words 49 times increase in value.**

Answer (score 1):

You can't use variable name starts with numbers

```
const fst_num = 50
const snd_num = 100

percentage = ((snd_num -fst_num) / fst_num) * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const fst_num = 70192.32
const snd_num = 17548.08

const percentage = ( 100 - ( ( fst_num - snd_num ) / fst_num ) * 100 );
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.